# How to let code users input in code tags go trough HTML Purifier or how to make shure user input is safe without HTML Purifier

Tags: xss, htmlpurifier

I have a forum on my site where users can input markdown code. First i convert the markdown into HTML, then i purify the generated HTML with HTML Purifier and insert it into my database. But when users put in code for snippets, ect.. HTML Purifier removes the code from the post..

How can I fix this? Or should I look for an alternative to HTML Purifier?